# Is it possible to view file as HTML (for example file1.html) with WOPI (Office Web integration)? and how?

Tags: c#, .net, backend, ms-office, ms-wopi

Does WOPI has possibility to return file as HTML, when I read documentation there was like, .doc or .docx so I am interested if there is any ways to view file as HTML

I read the documentation of WOPI and there was too little information about that, Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file formats supported by a WOPI client are defined in the [discovery.xml file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/discovery).
You can check Office Online Server's discovery file here: https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery

Generally, only Open Office XML file formats (docx, xlsx) and a couple of related formats are supported. HTML is not one of them.